# Angular 4 how we can escape dot (.) in array key?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an array that its key is like `key.text` something like this:[image]

What i want to do is how can scape `.` inside array when want to use in `*ngFor`

I have this:

```
<span *ngFor="let dataByField of myArray">
   <span *ngFor="let dataByCompany of dataByField?.company.name">
     <li (click)="searchByWorkType(dataByCompany?._id)"><a>{{ dataByCompany?._id }}<span class="badge badge-default pull-right item-plus-icon-custom-style">{{ dataByCompany.total }}</span></a></li>
   </span>
</span>
```

My question is how to handle `.` in `*ngFor="let dataByCompany of dataByField?.company.name"`?
I have a condition to not change `company.name` to some thing else.

Comment: Try `dataByField['company.name']`

Comment: Are you saying that the object looks like `{"company.name": "value"}` vs. `{company: {name: "value"}}`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes exactly like that.

Comment: I wonder what was/is the reason for that design decision